# String replace didn't work inside checkbox uncheck event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a trouble about in javascript replace function. Please pointing to me where might be wrong. I have a value that contain "ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR". After un-checked checkbox, the checkbox value remove form my **uniqueList** value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute" class="attribute" value="ONE"> ONE
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute" class="attribute" value="TWO"> TWO
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute" class="attribute" value="THREE"> THREE
<input type="checkbox" name="attribute" class="attribute" value="FOUR"> FOUR
```

Javascript is;

```
var uniqueList = "ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR";
$('.attribute').click(function() {
    var val = (this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');            
    if(val=='unchecked'){
        uniqueList =  uniqueList.replace($(this).val(),"");                       
    } 
});

alert(uniqueList);  //no uniiqueList value in alert
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhxtkutd/5/)**

Comment: If you want to `alert` it each time, then place the `alert` inside the handler - your code works fine for removing from the string.

Comment: @tymeJV I want to get finalize string value outside the handler. It's work inside handler. But, I can't get this value outside the handler.

Comment: You have it outside! Your code doesnt do anything with it!

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zuhp2tqx/?

Answer (score 1):

Since the handler is after your declaration, it doesn't mean that it will also execute in the same way for it is an event handler and gets invoked only when it gets triggered, either by code or manually. So you would need to trigger it in your code.

```
var uniqueList = "ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR";
$('.attribute').click(function() {
    var val = (this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
    if (val == 'unchecked') {
        uniqueList = uniqueList.replace($(this).val(), "");
    }
}).trigger("click"); // triggering it invokes the handler
alert(uniqueList); // it works now
```